# Obtener propiedad de un objeto dentro de un array de objetos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo el siguiente json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo converti a array con Object.values(this.ArrayUserAuth);
y quedo de esta manera↓

```
ArrayUserAuth = [
0:{avatar
: 
"https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"
email
: 
"janet.weaver@reqres.in"
first_name
: 
"Janet"
id
: 
2
last_name
: 
"Weaver"},

1:{
text: "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
url: 
"https://reqres.in/#support-heading"}
]
```

Necesito acceder solo al objeto 0 y a el valor de la propiedad email.
Intenté con for each o en template con *ngFor pero nada.

o puedo acceder desde el json original a dicho valor?

Comment: ¿Viste [esta pregunta](/questions/444427)?

Comment: JSON!= Objeto JS

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas entrar al mismo por su propiedad en un objeto quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
UserAuth = {
  0: {
    avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg",
    email: "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Janet",
    id: 2,
    last_name: "Weaver",
  },
  1: {
    text: "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!",
    url: "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
  },
};

console.log(UserAuth[0].email)
//Se usa bracket notation para acceder al objeto por ser un numero la clave en este caso.
```

Otra opción podría ser tener un array e ingresar por su posición, entonces quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
const ArrayUserAuth = [
  {
    avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg",
    email: "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Janet",
    id: 2,
    last_name: "Weaver",
  },

  {
    text: "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!",
    url: "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
  },
];

console.log(ArrayUserAuth[0].email)
```

Comment: Hola amigo hice una aclaracion sobre el tipo de array que estoy trabajando originalmente es un json como el de la imagen necesito acceder a email como podria hacerlo lo que me dejaste no me funciono

Comment: Creo que quizás no sea necesario convertirlo con Object.values, podrías recorrer el json facilmente.

Comment: Habría que ver bien la estructura, en realidad ninguno de los ejemplos son json, el pasado por Object.values creo que solo te complicará la vida, y el otro está contraído entonces es imposible ver cual es su estructura..

Answer (score 0):

Podrías almacenar los objetos en una constante y luego acceder a ella:

```js
// Definimos al objeto en una constante.
const ArrayUserAuth = {
  0: {
    avatar: 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg',
    email: 'janet.weaver@reqres.in',
    first_name: 'Janet',
    id: 2,
    last_name: 'Weaver',
  },

  1: {
    text: 'To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!',
    url: 'https://reqres.in/#support-heading',
  },
};

// Ingresamos al objeto, de la posición 0, la propiedad email.
console.log(ArrayUserAuth[0].email)
```

Comment: La explicación de esta solución está mal... NO estás creando un array, eso jamás será un array, el hecho de que puedas acceder a sus propiedades con `ArrayUserAuth[0]` eso no lo convierte en un array. Lo que estás creando es un objeto, con las claves "0" y "1" y accediendo a ellas. Si fuera un array `console.log(ArrayUserAuth.length)` retornaría 2, pero retorna `undefined`. Así como tampoco puedes usar `map` ni `reduce` ni `find` ni ninguno de los metodos propios de un array. Y tampoco aporta nada distinto a la solucion de Luis. S romero

Comment: Listo ya edité mi respuesta, gracias por la aclaración, había observado mal las llaves. Entonces no concuerda el título con la descripción del problema.

Comment: De echo, revisa las ediciones, primero habla de objetos / array, ahora de un JSON :/.